# /usr/lib/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas

Tags: python, compiling, libraries, shared-library

I am working on a remote machine via **ssh** and **don't have sudo permissions**.  Currently, I am trying to run a python project which imports the keras framework. Due to an old version of **openblas** I was forced to manually compile the current version of Openblas by cloning [this](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git) project. Though Keras does not struggle anymore with old libraries a new problem occured when python hits this line:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

I get the error `/usr/lib/libblas.so.3: undefined symbol: gotoblas`.

There are some similar issues out there, but I cannot simply remove `libopenblas-base` as suggested in some solutions due to missing sudo permissions.

I think I could figure out where the problem is rooted.

```
readelf -Ws /home/me/lib/lib/libopenblas.so.0 | grep gotoblas
  1019: 0000000000283b20   256 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 gotoblas_pthread
  2556: 000000000007f200    29 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 gotoblas_quit
  2576: 000000000007f220    76 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 gotoblas_init
  2597: 0000000000faffd0     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   24 gotoblas_initialized
  9916: 0000000000283b20   256 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 gotoblas_pthread
 10873: 000000000007f220    76 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 gotoblas_init
 13330: 000000000007f200    29 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 gotoblas_quit
```

As you can see there is no "gotoblas" defined in the manually installed openblas version. For that reason the exception in the title is thrown. On my personal computer I get the following output:

```
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0 | grep gotoblas
  ....
  6146: 0000000002089d30     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 gotoblas
  6779: 000000000206c240  3992 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 gotoblas_DUNNINGTON
  ....
```

There it is! Can somebody explain me how to manually install OpenBlas such that the upper error does not occur anymore? Apparently, only a small part is installed when compiling OpenBlas manually. Its directory contains the following files:

```
ls /home/me/lib/lib/
cmake  libopenblas.a  libopenblas.so  libopenblas.so.0  libopenblas_sandybridgep-r0.2.19.a  libopenblas_sandybridgep-r0.2.19.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have two version of libblas. You can try to select another library installed in your sistem like this:

```
update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3 
update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
```

But if you don't have permissions you will have to change your .bashrc file and modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH and possibly PYTHONPATH environment variables.

Try:

```
locate libbas.so.3
```

To see if there are more versions of this library in your system, and use its path and append it to your .bashrc like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<your library path, without file name>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_PRELOAD=<your library path>
```

I did not try ... let me know if it works.